# Change shortcut for Frame Selected

Tags: shortcut

In 3D view editor (and most of the others) there is a function **Frame Selected** that brings selected in center of view. By default its shortcut <kbd>Numpad</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> , since I stacked at home with keyboard without numpad – How can I reassign shortcut to something else?

[image]

---

Note: When I tried it from *User Prefferences > Keymap > Search by name Frame Selected* the only one listed is function for Node editor that adds selected Nodes into a Frame )it has nothing to do with the view function).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: Resolved for 2.83+** https://developer.blender.org/T75107

**For version 2.82a** - it turns out there is inconsistency with the text. In the Keymap, I can't find "frame selected", and instead it is actually "View Selected".

[image]

Comment: also I think this should be reported to the UI dev to be fixed

Comment: It came to my mind, but I was such stack with the name and growing angry, that I looked everywhere around for possible issue, so ... as ussually  - hidden in the shadow :) Thank you, so much. I will try to move forward.

Comment: A couple of years late on this one, but in 2.83 onwards you can right-click on the menu item and choose 'Change Shortcut' or 'Add to Quick favorites'.